# AWS Appsync - unable to find User Pool Client ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Now I'm using AWS AppSync and Cognito. I wrote schema of AppSync. But I can't test the schema in Queries tab. Running query requires user authentication and I can't find User pool client ID.
Where can I find it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The User Pool Client ID is available from the Amazon Cognito User Pools console in [the App Clients section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html).

[image]

You should create an App Client if it doesn't already exist. Make sure to uncheck the "Generate client secret" box.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In the new UI, it's in *App Integration* tab in *App client list(App clients and analytics)* section on the bottom.

See attached image for details.

[image]